# cshtml: Display date in MM/dd/yyyy format in non editable text box

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, datepicker

There was a text box (editable) with datepicker to select date of user joining. My task is to set the joining date of all new user to current date by default and for old users it should be display the date in which the user joined(this will be retrieved from DB). And I have to make the text box as non editable readonly. Also I have to remove the datepicker for that textbox. The date format I have to display is MM/dd/yyyy. I have done some changes in code and now datepicker is removed and I can also display the date but not in required format, it is displaying like, Tue May 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). I need to display it like 05/12/2016.

**cshtml code:**

```
<input type="text" id="StartingDate" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-bind="value: userInfo.StartingDate" readonly />
```

**jscode:**

```
function getStartingDate() {
      var defaultDate = userInfo.StartingDate() || new Date(new Date()).toDateString();

      StartingDateValue(defaultDate);

      $('#StartingDate').on('focusout', function () {
        var startingDate = StartingDateValue() || new Date();
        $('#StartingDate').val(StartingDate.toLocaleDateString());
      });
    }
```

I am getting correct date values but in different format. I am trying to fix it from yesterday. But could not. 
Can you please point out where the things getting wrong ?

To be clear, My code result like this,

[image]

But I need to diplay in this format,

[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:)

Try to reconstruct DateTime string as like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="yourDatepickerId"/>   <!--Here is your DateTime picker-->
```

JS:

```
var dateObj = document.getElementById("yourDatepickerId").value;  //<--Here is you get DateTime  value from picker

 var newDate = new Date(dateObj);
 var formattedString = [newDate.getMonth()+1,newDate.getDate(),newDate.getFullYear()].join("/");

 alert(formattedString ); //Result : mm/d/yyyy
```

Comment: `var formattedString = [newDate.Month()+1,newDate.Date(),newDate.getFullYear()].join("/");` It results in exception error. `Object doesn't support property or method 'Month'` like that for Date and getfullyear too

Comment: No it is not working in my case. It results in same error again. Thanks for reply @Praguan

Comment: @MJSuriya, Sorry, I 've  a mistake in code, I corrected it now ;)   should be: newDate.getMonth()+1, try it now